# React and Reloading API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project in React that pulls random data from an API and processes it. Currently, on loading the page, that component that actually pulls the API doesn't load by design.

So to keep things simple, I have two Components. I load `Component1` and using a state `showDiv: false` I don't load `Component2` with the API call. I have a button that when clicked changes the state to `true`, and by doing that, loads `Component2` inside `Component1`.

Now what I want to do is have `Component2` hidden again, and then brought back, and call a new set of data from the API and process it. I wrongly assumed that once `Component2` was pulled off the page, that bringing it back would load it from scratch eg. rerun the `componentWillMount()` function inside `Component2`, which is where my API call is located. Now that I see that's not the case, I'm not sure how to accomplish that without reloading the page entirely.

EDIT:

Here's the component to be rendered:
*(This has been heavily simplified. The API pulls an array, and that array is processed into an array of objects, and then it is placed in the state. The component's render is then populated by content taken from that processed array from the state)*

```
class Questions extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isQuestionLoaded: false,
      questions: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    fetch(this.props.category)
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
        let questions = data.results.map((question) => {
            return question;
        })
        this.setState({questions: questions, isQuestionLoaded: true});
      })
  }
```

Here's the App.js render of this component:

```
render() {

let questionRender = this.state.showQuestions ?
  <Questions
    category={ this.state.categoryActive }
    questionNumber={ this.state.questionNumber }
    onClickCorrect={ this.nextQuestionCorrect }
    onClickCorrectLast={ this.lastQuestionCorrect }
    onClickIncorrect={ this.nextQuestionIncorrect }
    onClickIncorrectLast={ this.lastQuestionIncorrect }
    score={ this.state.score }
    correct={ this.state.correct }
    answerCorrect={ this.state.answerCorrect } />
    : null;
```

Here's the function that takes the component away:

```
  lastQuestionCorrect() {
    this.setState({
      showQuestions: false, 
      showFinal: true
    });
  }
```

Here's the function that brings the component back:

```
  onClickReplay() {
    this.setState({
      showQuestions: true,
      showFinal: false,
    });
  }
```

Comment: This should work, please provide a reproduction of your problem

Comment: @Axnyff Edited the post to include more information. Tried to cut out as much unnecessary code as possible. Thanks

Comment: try with console whether it is going to 2nd component or not , check response of api and check whether it is calling or not

Comment: @yogeshagrawal this helped me narrow down the problem. A new array was being loaded, the problem was one of my states in `App.js` was not being reset correctly by `onClickReplay()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new array was being loaded, the problem was one of my states in `App.js` was not being reset correctly by `onClickReplay()`

Comment: is it going inside that function check with console once and check your  `this.state.showQuestions` what ouput is coming